# Variance across row in h2o

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to calculate variance of multiple columns across each row.
Hence the result would have dimension no_of_rows*1.

I tried following way:

```
import pandas as pd    
test = pd.DataFrame({'p1':[0.8,0.7,0.3],'p10':[0.4,0.6,0.3],'p11':[0.9,0.6,0.4],'p12':[0.44,9.8,0.4],'p13':[0.8,0.4,0.5],'p14':[0.7,0.7,0.7],'p15':[0.8,0.8,0.5]})
test_h2o = h2o.H2OFrame(test)
test_h2o[['p1','p10','p11','p12','p13','p14','p15']].head().apply(lambda x: x.var(),1)
```

and I get the error "Expected a Frame but found a class water.rapids.vals.ValRow".
However with mean as function it works

```
test_h2o[['p1','p10','p11','p12','p13','p14','p15']].head().apply(lambda x: x.mean(),1)
```

Comment: Please edit the question so it contains a reproducible example.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @ErinLeDell thanks for pointing out and I have edited the question, hope it helps. I ended up using spark to compute it but any pointers on how it can be done using h2o directly would be helpful.